# Page that fit the screen without scrollbars

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm working on [my web site](http://mylocation.altervista.org).
If you go to the page after the login, you can see that the page scrolls horizontally and vertically.
Is it possible to make the page fit the entire screen without need of the scrollbar?
I'm using materialize and the second column of the site (the pale blue part) has a 2px margin.

Thank you!

(for the login "prova" and "prova")

SOLVED:

```
body {
overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to get past the login screen? Also, you are missing a required doctype on the login which makes me believe you are missing one on the rest of the site, too.

Comment: try "prova" and "prova"

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Just turn off scrolling. You can get the screen width and height at the beginning. Then write something like this to update your component sizes.

```
function updateSize() {

var winWidth  = $(window).width(),

winHeight = $(window).height();

$('.loginButton').css({

width:winWidth * 0.2,

height:winHeight * 0.2

});

}

$(window).resize(function() {

updateSize();

});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without JS?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it.
Another question:

What's the line "$:('.loginButton').css()";

Comment: @RobertoAureli Yes, it is possible to do so without javascript. In fact, there is no reason to use js at all.

Comment: It's just an example on how to get and modify the size of an html component. You can replace that code with any of your html component's class or id that you want to change it's size.@RobertoAureli

Comment: @Rob how can I do it?

Comment: Another way would be to use it like button {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
} It provides a non JS solution as @Rob mentioned

Comment: @SerhanOztekin you code throws me an error: $ is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You have a 2px margin on `#map` that's causing the horizontal scroll bar.

You need to add a doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`. All modern web pages require this or else you will be in ["quirks mode"](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/); a place you never want to be. Adding that may change your layout to some extent but you started out in quirks. You don't want to be in quirks.

Comment: Can i remove the scollbar without removing the margin?
And for the vertical one?

(i've added the doctype)

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the 2px margin.

Comment: Only for "aesthetic" reasons

Comment: You need to look into your actual widths to see if they are adding up to 100% in actual pixels. Absolutely positioning that element is taking it out of the normal flow and making it overflow the body which is what is causing the horizontal scrollbar. The problem, vertically, is more work than can be handled here and should probably be a separate question after you fix the horizontal one.

Comment: Pratically what should I do? Set it to relative?